# Nested for loops slow python for calculating special standard deviation

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, optimization, networkx

I am trying to calculate the standard deviation for topological properties in matrices of around 100 nodes. What I am trying to code is the following:

how to calculate the standard deviation

[image]

(there needs to be a square bracket closing this)

Where X is

how to calculate the topological property X

[image]

but a should be replaced with g.

As a result I coded the following. I trial ran the code with a random graph of about 85 nodes. Therefor, `S` and `G` are both an 85 by 85 matrix where all entries are floats between 0 and 1 and `n` is the number of nodes, 85 in this case. Input into the code is `M_std` (type = numpy.ndarray, `S` in input of function), which is a matrix of standard deviations of g_{ij}, and `M_p` (type = numpy.ndarray, G in input of function) is a matrix of the expectational values of g_{ij}. `Derivative` refers the (delta X)/(delta g_{ij}). `Std_1` is everything in between the square.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import math

def new_calc_std_1(S, G, n):
    std_1 = 0
    for e in range(n):
        for f in range(n):
            derivative = 0
            for i in range(n):
                for j in range(n):
                    for k in range(n):
                        if i == j or i == k or j == k:
                            None
                        elif (e not in [i,j,k]) or (f not in [i,j,k]):
                            None
                        else:
                            if e == i and f == j:
                                deriv += -G[j,i]*G[j,k]*(1-G[k,j])*(1-G[i,k])*(1-G[k,i])
                            elif e == j and f == i:
                                deriv += (1-G[i,j])*G[j,k]*(1-G[k,j])*(1-G[i,k])*(1-G[k,i])
                            elif e == j and f == k:
                                deriv += (1-G[i,j])*G[j,i]*(1-G[k,j])*(1-G[i,k])*(1-G[k,i])
                            elif e == k and f == j:
                                deriv += -(1-G[i,j])*G[j,i]*G[j,k]*(1-G[i,k])*(1-G[k,i])
                            elif e == i and f == k:
                                deriv += -(1-G[i,j])*G[j,i]*G[j,k]*(1-G[k,j])*(1-G[k,i])
                            elif e == k and f == i:
                                deriv += -(1-G[i,j])*G[j,i]*G[j,k]*(1-G[k,j])*(1-G[i,k])
                            else:
                                derivative += 0
            std_1 += (S[e,f]*derivative)**2
    std_1 = math.sqrt(std_1)
    return std_1
```

This took a total of 21 minutes. I tried find a solution so then I read that I had to minimize the use of for loops, especially in python. Therefor I rewrote the code to

```
def new_new_calc_std_1(S, G, n):
    blwsqrt = 0
    for e in range(n):
        for f in range(n):
            derivative = 0
            for z in range(n):
                if e == f or f == z or z == e:
                    None
                else:
                    derivative += -G[f,e]*G[f,z]*(1-G[z,f])*(1-G[e,z])*(1-G[z,e]) - (1-G[e,z])*G[z,e]*G[z,f]*(1-G[f,z])*(1-G[f,e]) + (1-G[f,e])*G[e,z]*(1-G[z,e])*(1-G[f,z])*(1-G[z,f]) - (1-G[f,z])*G[z,f]*G[z,e]*(1-G[e,z])*(1-G[f,e]) + (1-G[z,e])*G[e,z]*(1-G[f,e])*(1-G[z,f])*(1-G[f,z]) - (1-G[z,f])*G[f,z]*G[f,e]*(1-G[z,e])*(1-G[e,z])
            blwsqrt += (derivative*S[e,f])**2
    std_1 = math.sqrt(blwsqrt)
    return(std_1)

print(new_new_calc_std_1(M_std, M_p, n))
```

which to my surprise took exactly the same time. I then tried to round the matrices. This didn't work either. I then read that I might be using too much python and should use scipy more, but I do not know how in this specific instance. **Do you guys know how to optimize this code to make it take a shorter amount of time than 21 minutes, or is this just what I have to deal with**. This is an updated version of the previous post. I am very sorry for the last one.

P.S. I am using a 2,5 GHz Intel Core 5 and running the calculation in jupyter notebook.

P.P.S an example of `M_std` is

```
[[0.45 0.39 0.45 ... 0.41 0.43 0.39]
 [0.5  0.46 0.5  ... 0.48 0.49 0.47]
 [0.5  0.46 0.49 ... 0.47 0.49 0.46]
 ...
 [0.48 0.42 0.47 ... 0.44 0.46 0.43]
 [0.5  0.46 0.49 ... 0.47 0.49 0.46]
 [0.47 0.42 0.47 ... 0.43 0.46 0.42]]
```

and `M_p`

```
[[0.29 0.18 0.28 ... 0.21 0.25 0.19]
 [0.45 0.31 0.44 ... 0.35 0.4  0.32]
 [0.44 0.3  0.42 ... 0.34 0.39 0.31]
 ...
 [0.35 0.23 0.34 ... 0.26 0.31 0.24]
 [0.43 0.3  0.42 ... 0.34 0.39 0.31]
 [0.33 0.22 0.33 ... 0.25 0.29 0.23]]
```

Comment: if this is working code and you want to optimize it code review SE would be a better place to ask

Comment: I thought this was allright, as I have seen similar questions on this same stack, but not exactly applicable to my problem.

Comment: how big are your matrixes? seems like O(n * n * n) code

Comment: my matrices are 85 by 85. And thanks for the correction!

Comment: For my first solution, there are 5 for loops, for my second solution there are only 3. That's why I was surprised about the similar run times

Comment: @ThomasMcDonald the *number of loops* doesn't matter if they are doing the equivalent thing.

Comment: @ThomasMcDonald the reason the second one takes the same is because you never called it, you are calling your old function new_calc_std_1 instead of new_new_calc_std_1. Currently your new function has typos or missing data such as k variable

Comment: Oh wow, I am extremely stupid, going to try it right now!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga number of loops is what changes from O(n^5) to O(n^3) as operations inside loops are all O(1)...

Comment: @juvian sorry, but it doesn't work that way. While it is a decent rule-of-thumb that the number of loops corresponds to the degree of the polynomial, you can write any single-loops as a nested loop (and so on and so forth), and the complexity won't change. Now, I haven't analysed the above code in detail to say either way, but just because you change the number of loops in your code it won't change the complexity/runtime necessarily.

Comment: I now get the problem: "only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices" but I will have to figure this out right now

Comment: @ThomasMcDonald update your question with your current code

Comment: I added in the condition that e, f and z can not be equal as in the second linked picture. also now I put in new_new_ instead of new_

Comment: @ThomasMcDonald please correct all typos first. there is no j declared, there is no k declared yet you use them in the function. You should be seeing these errors when trying to run the code

Comment: Yes I see it now too, I did not expect this will do this in the coming five minutes. Thanks for the help already!

Comment: IT WORKED!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH, IT TOOK LIKE 10 SECONDS!!

Comment: @juvian you are a god among men

Comment: I just got back with my lunch -- I'm glad to see the improved posting *and a solution*!!

Comment: no problem ^^. You had already optimized it yourself, just needed it to run :P

Comment: just for everybodies information. The calculation time got reduced from `1347.233815908432` seconds to `8.8506920337677` seconds!

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using Python2, I'd advise using `xrange` instead of `range`. `xrange` is more efficient, as it doesn't generate the entire sequence upfront.

I'd also advise using `itertools.product` instead of nested for loops.

Try something like `for (e,f,z) in product(xrange(n), xrange(n), xrange(n)):`

[`product` docs link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)